# Nature of the array created by numpy.empty([])

Tags: python, numpy

I was creating a `numpy.empty([0])` array and accidentally typed `numpy.empty([])`.

This created an numpy array with the string representation

```
array(0.)
```

with size

```
>>> numpy.empty([]).size
1
```

and shape

```
>>> numpy.empty([]).shape
()
```

**Question:** what is the nature of this object?

I couldn't deduce it from the [documentation of `numpy.empty`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html).
In particular, what I find most confusing is the `0.` that appears in the string representation, which seems to be a `float(0.0)`. <strike>If it is somehow representing an element, this is not accessible.</strike> I was trying to access it as `numpy.empty([])[0]`.

The object is different in nature from the one created by `numpy.empty([0])`, which has size

```
>>> numpy.empty([0]).size
0
```

and shape

```
>>> numpy.empty([0]).shape
(0,)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a 0-dimensional array. The first argument to `numpy.empty` indicates how long you want each dimension to be, and passing a length-0 list means you don't want any dimensions.

There is exactly one element in any 0-dimensional array, accessible by indexing it with a tuple of 0 indices:

```
arr[()]
```

The element happened to be 0.0 this time, but that's not a guarantee, since you used `numpy.empty`.

Comment: I guess that they put an element in it due to $\prod_{i\in D}d_i$ being $1$ if $D$ is the empty set.

Answer (score 1):

- `np.empty([10, 10, 10])` creates a 3-dimensional array, with size 10x10x10 or 10<sup>3</sup>
- `np.empty([10, 10])` creates a 2-dimensional array, with size 10x10 or 10<sup>2</sup>
- `np.empty([10])` creates a 1-dimensional array, with size 10 or 10<sup>1</sup>
- `np.empty([])` creates a 0-dimensional array, with size 1  or 10<sup>0</sup>